# How do i apply multiple classList.toggle which should have the same class with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a beginner in javascript so I'm still learning but I have the impression that my code is too repetitive but I don't know how to improve it, moreover I try to apply the same code to the same html element which have the same id or the same class but it doesn't work every time it applies only to the first element.

Thanks in advance to those who will help me.

```
    <body>
        <section>
                <div id="prj1" class="projet-contain">
                    <div class="preview">
                        <a >Projet Convertigo</a>
                        <img class="arrow-down" src="images/down-arrow-svgrepo-com.svg">
                        <img src="images/Convertigo.png" class="convertigo" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div id="projet1">
                        <a>c'est la div 1</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="prj2" class="projet-contain">
                    <div class="preview">
                        <a >Projet Convertigo</a>
                        <img class="arrow-down" src="images/down-arrow-svgrepo-com.svg">
                        <img src="images/Convertigo.png" class="convertigo" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div id="projet2">
                        <a>c'est la div 2</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="prj3" class="projet-contain">
                    <div class="preview">
                        <a >Projet Convertigo</a>
                        <img class="arrow-down" src="images/down-arrow-svgrepo-com.svg">
                        <img src="images/Convertigo.png" class="convertigo" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div id="projet3">
                        <a>c'est la div 3</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
     </body>
    <style> .projet-contain{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(238,174,202,0.200) 0%, rgba(148, 188, 233, 0.200) 100%);;
        border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        user-select: none;
    }
    
    .preview{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    section >div>div >a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
    }
    
    .convertigo{
        width: 10vw;
        
    }
    
    
    .arrow-down {
        transition: transform 0.5s;
        width: 1.5vw;
        
        -webkit-filter: invert(100%); /* safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
                filter: invert(100%);
                
    }
    
    .rotate-arrow {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    </style>
<script>
const projet1 = document.getElementById("projet1");
const projet2 = document.getElementById("projet2");
const projet3 = document.getElementById("projet3");

const prj = document.getElementById("prj");
var arrow = document.querySelectorAll(".arrow-down")[0]

projet1.style.display = "none";
projet2.style.display = "none";
projet3.style.display = "none";

prj1.onclick = function () {
    if (projet1.style.display !== "none") {
        projet1.style.display = "none";
        arrow.classList.toggle('rotate-arrow')

    } else {
        projet1.style.display = "flex";
        arrow.classList.toggle('rotate-arrow')

    }
    console.log("prj1");
};

prj2.onclick = function () {
    if (projet2.style.display !== "none") {
        projet2.style.display = "none";
        arrow.classList.toggle('rotate-arrow')

    } else {
        projet2.style.display = "flex";
        arrow.classList.toggle('rotate-arrow')

    }
    console.log("prj2");

};

prj3.onclick = function () {
    if (projet3.style.display !== "none") {
        projet3.style.display = "none";
        arrow.classList.toggle('rotate-arrow')

    } else {
        projet3.style.display = "flex";
        arrow.classList.toggle('rotate-arrow')

    }
    console.log("pr3");

};
</script>
```